# Which is the preferred way of using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to create a single file executable for my program. I can get it to work with the `pyinstaller` command and also by editing a `.spec` file to add the options I need.

I am wondering which is the preferred way of doing thins? or in other words: Should I have a spec file in my git repository or a shell script with all the parameters.